# Python Beautiful soup Get_Text coming back '-'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using beautiful soup. My code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

web_address = ('xxxx') # this part is fine I don't want to provide website.

req = urllib2.Request(web_address)


page = urllib2.urlopen(req)    

content = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
td = soup.findAll('td')
for line in td:
    print(line.get_text())
```

The portion of the HTML I am looking at is:

```
<td class="border_TopRight border_Left">
    Text - "TEST_NAME
<td class="border_TopRight">
    Text - TEST_NAME_1
<td class="border_TopRight">
    Text - TEST_NAME_2
<td class="apple dataCell border_TopRight font_green" id="Number of Apples" style="color: #333333; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" rel="Apples ">
    Text - 999999.999
```

My output of my python script is:

```
TEST_NAME
TEST_NAME_1
TEST_NAME_2
 -
```

I can't figure out why the last output in '-'. I have read through the BS4 docs and can't seem to find out why the first 3 come back with the correct text, but the last one is '-'

Comment: I have no problem printing the last text as `Text - 999999.999`. Can you post the full `content`? I believe the issue is lying on somewhere else

Comment: It appears that the page intial loads with '-' and then after a few seconds the data cells loads (999999.999). It seems that I need a delay of some point

Comment: Is the content dynamically generated? If so, it's not going to happen for the python script. urllib2 doesn't have a javascript engine to know how to populate that data.